# Shiny CSS not work for fonts

Tags: html, css, shinydashboard

I have the following css in which I set the background and font:

```
    .my_style_1{  background-image:url(field.jpg);
                  background-repeat: no-repeat;
                  background-size: cover;
                  height:950px;
                  font-size: 1.5em;
                  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; ;
                  font-weight:500;
                  color: rgb(255,255,255)}
```

and in ui.R I am using the following:

```
    fluidRow(
              box(width=12,
                  class="my_style_1",
                  div(br(),h1("Travel Diary"),style="position:relative;right:150px;text-align: center;")                      
              )
```

My problem now is it seems like only the background css is working- not matter how I changed the font size it didnt work! However I did observe that when I increased the font size- the `br()` height increases but i don't know what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. I used the wrong tag `h1`. Once I changed it to `p` it actuallly worked.